# Intuitive Sense of Outer Product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I am trying to establish an intuitive sense of what the outer product does.

I came across the following assertion on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-intuitive-understanding-of-the-outer-product-of-two-vectors):

> The outer product between two vectors, U, and V, gives us a matrix. Every matrix acts as a transformation on vectors. That is, given a vector, W, their outer product transforms W into another vector. Now, this might be obvious to you, but what obviously isn’t so obvious is what it transforms it into. Specifically,
>   $$(UV^T)W =  (V\cdot W)U$$

As far as I can tell, this is wrong.

For example, given: 
U = [1, 3]
V = [3, 4]
W = [2, 3]

LHS:
$$UV^T=15$$
$$15*W=[30,45]$$

RHS:
$$V\cdot W = 18$$
$$18*U = [18,54]$$

Based on this working, the LHS is not equivalent to the RHS.

Fwiw, if I interpret the Quora poster's vector W as the outerproduct of U and V, the assertion still does not hold up.

$$U\otimes V = W = \begin{bmatrix} 6 & 9 \\ 8 & 12 \end{bmatrix}$$

LHS:
$$(UV^T)W = 15*\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 9 \\ 8 & 12\end{bmatrix}$$

RHS:
$$V\cdot W = [25,75] $$
$$(V\cdot W)U = [25,75][1,3] $$

Which is also not equivalent to the assertion:

$$(UV^T)W =  (V\cdot W)U$$

Two questions:
1. Am I doing something wrong here? Or am I correct in saying the Quora poster is wrong?
2. What is an intuitive description of an outer product?

Comment: Vectors are supposed to be *column* vectors here, not rows. That is why your results are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The claim with your choice of $U$, $V$ ,and $W$ is $$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}3 & 4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix} = \left(\begin{bmatrix}3 & 4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}\right) \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}.$$
The left-hand side is
$$\begin{bmatrix}3 & 4 \\ 9 & 12\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}18 \\ 54\end{bmatrix}.$$
The right-hand side is
$$18 \begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}=  \begin{bmatrix}18 \\ 54\end{bmatrix}.$$

The original claim is essentially just associativity ofmatrix multiplication.

Comment: How do you know to do $U^T$ rather than $V^T$?

Comment: @Sean As Ted Shifrin pointed out, vectors are usually treated as column vectors, not row vectors.